# Hide ribbon of Access 2016

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to disable all default toolbar and ribbons of Access when it runs and so far the remaining problem I have is the ribbon.

I follow this tutorial
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837012.aspx

but my ribbon still shows when Access starts. At first I thought I wasn't able to add the table properly because it doesn't show on my table list but when I tried to add it again a message prompt me that the table already exist so I assume that the table is something that really doesn't show on my table list.

However, my problem is that the ribbon is still showing with limited buttons enabled. I want to completely remove it or at least disable all buttons.

The article said
Applies to: Access 2013 | Office 2013

Anyone knows how to achieve this in Access 2016 (office 365)

Comment: Have you tried this? `DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo`

Comment: @HansUp wow! such a simple code for my big problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo Works in Access 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That [linked page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837012.aspx) *"describes how to load a customized ribbon that hides all of the built-in tabs."*

If you just want to hide the ribbon entirely, it would be simpler to use ...

```vb
DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
```

If you want to hide the ribbon, but allow the user to display it again later at their discretion, use ...

```vb
DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarWhereApprop
```

I described those methods based on what I see with Access 2010, and I hope they work the same in 2016.