# MSAccess: Hiding Navigation Pane, and Menu Bar Using VBAccess

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, menu, ms-access-2010

Is there a way to hide the Navigation Pane, and Menu Bar on launch using MSAccess VB? Point is to remove "distractions" from users using MSAccess solution.

**Fig A: Hiding the Navigation Pane and Menu Bar**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Option 1

One easy way is to rename the `*.accdb` to `*.accdr`.

Then it will be opened in runtime mode without ribbon bar and navigation pane.

## Option 2

Call the database by full command line of Microsoft Access and the database and the command line parameter `/runtime`, then it also will be opened in runtime mode.

Example:

`"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\msaccess.exe" "c:\data\yourDatabase.accdb" /runtime`

(the path of Microsoft Access varies regarding your installation of Access (msi or c2r, x86 or x64, version of access, custom installation folder...)

## Option 3

You can hide them by code:

- Navigation Pane: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47519552/7658533
- Ribbon: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35582657/7658533

Comment: The runtime mode is genius - this definitely works for me as well. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use below codes to hide navigation pane & ribbon to my databases. You can also try-

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error GoTo HarunErrHandler
    
'******************* Hide Ribbon and Navigation Pane ***************************

    DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
    Call DoCmd.NavigateTo("acNavigationCategoryObjectType")
    Call DoCmd.RunCommand(acCmdWindowHide)

'*******************************************************************************

Exit Sub
HarunErrHandler:
MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbInformation, "Error"
End Sub
```

If you need to show them again then use below codes.

```
'******************* Show Ribbon and Navigation Pane ***************************

    DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarYes
    Call DoCmd.SelectObject(acTable, , True)

'*******************************************************************************
```