# hide navigation pane in Access using vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

All the suggestions so far; are NOT working.  When I load a form I want its load event to trigger and hide the objects navigation pane.  For some reason, I cannot set the focus correctly on the pane...The result hides my form instead.

```
Private Sub Form_load()
    call Main
End Sub

Sub Main()
    DoCmd.NavigateTo "acNavigationCategoryObjectType"
    DoCmd.RunCommand (acCmdWindowHide)
End Subtype here
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MSAccess: Hiding Navigation Pane, and Menu Bar Using VBAccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554029/msaccess-hiding-navigation-pane-and-menu-bar-using-vbaccess)

Comment: Nope... sorry... the OP who offered that solution (at bottom of that thread) didn't include  anything other than how to inspect and verify if the active window was a form or the pane.  He did not include any examples of how to mitigate or get the focus onto the pane.  And that is precisely the problem I am facing. I cant seem to get the focus where it needs to be.

Comment: Use `DoCmd.SelectObject acTable, , True` instead of NavigateTo. This is shown in link within accepted answer and works for me. Keep in mind that F11 will still expand the pane.

Comment: Thanks;  but it doesn't seem to work for me.  Believe me;  I have tried every permutation discussed across multiple threads.   I confirmed  my active window focus  is always the form.     Why , after attempting to place the focus on the pane, (using the aforementioned code) does the select object Or the navigateto command still hit my form instead?

Comment: Don't know. Still works for me.

Comment: So I finally found the solution.  Its not enough just to throw those lines of code at it... There is some context to consider.   In this case, I created a splash screen to launch the code at load time.  (Load event fires everything before the screen actually appears.  So essentially the next best active screen was the pane.   This for some reason did not work when I used it in a Switchboard.