# hide ribbon and show toolbar in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I am hoping someone can give me the VBA code in access 2019 to show  the Custom Quick Access Toolbar and hide RIBBON (Hide File, home, create, .... )

In my research I have seen code to hide the main menu/ribbon, and which also hides the custom QAT:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide
DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
```

However, I want to keep the QAT and only hide the main menu/ribbon.

Comment: The code you posted does not hide ribbon. You want to customize the ribbon. Review https://www.accessribbon.de/en/, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/how-to-apply-a-custom-ribbon-when-starting-access

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide ribbon of Access 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35579965/hide-ribbon-of-access-2016)

Comment: For your info. Using language tags unrelated to your question is a sure way to be downvoted by someone that looks at your question and finds that is not a question in its area of experience. Please read the [faq]

Comment: Is there a way  or vba code to hide the OPTION  in file menu?

Comment: Another source to review https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/hide-file-menu-option-in-access-database/884ffff2-2ec7-4219-990d-271d6015b2a5